# Could not find declaration when path mapping the root dir

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecma

root/

1. test.ts
2. func.ts

tsconfig.json
`"baseUrl": ".", "paths": { "/*": ["./*"] },`

if i do `import "/func"` or `import "func.js"` in my test.ts everything works fine. However if i do `import "/func.js"` i suddenly get `Could not find a declaration file for module ... implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Thanks in advance